# How can I copy an node to a different Document without the DOMException?

Tags: java, android, xml

In My App, I want to copy a node from one document to another .

Here is the code.

```
Element entryElement, operationElement;
for (int i = 0; i < eventList.getLength(); i++) {
    entryElement = (Element) eventList.item(i);
    gsTag = entryElement.getAttribute("gs_tag");
    System.out.println(gsTag);
    if (gsTag.equals("insert") || gsTag.equals("update") || gsTag.equals("delete")) {
        entryElement =  (Element) entryElement.cloneNode(true);
        rootElement.appendChild(entryElement);
        operationElement = syncDom.createElement("batch:operation");
        entryElement.appendChild(operationElement);
        operationElement.setAttribute("type", gsTag);
    }
}
```

when doing `rootElement.appendChild(entryElement);` the domexception occurs , and I checked the exception's code is 4. In java API , this code means one element can only belong to one document, but I did already clone the node. Why did it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning the node doesn't change which document it belongs to, because it is an *exact* copy of the node. To add a node to a different document, you need to have the target document 'adopt' it, using the "importNode" method of Document:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean%29

Comment: entryElement = (Element) eventDom.importNode(entryElement, true);
    operationElement = eventDom.createElement("batch:operation");
    operationElement.setAttribute("type", gsTag);
    entryElement.appendChild(operationElement);
    
syncDom.adoptNode(entryElement);                                                               It works now without Domexception . But In syncDom , the content did not change..   what I want is to move or copy the entry element from eventDom to syncDOm

Comment: It works right now.....  I made some mistake to make this much harder to solve.  thank you for your advise.